# Using Java Domain Object Instead of Scala Case Class in Spark DataSet Creation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a Spark DataSet from an RDD using the RDD#toDS method.

However, instead of using the Scala case class to specify the schema, I want to use an existing domain object defined in a 3rd party library. But, when I do that I get the following error:

```
scala> import org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient
import org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient

scala> val patients = sc.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://mongodb/fhir.patients")))
patients: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD[org.bson.Document] = MongoRDD[0] at RDD at MongoRDD.scala:47

scala> val patientsDataSet = patients.toDS[Patient]()
<console>:44: error: not enough arguments for method toDS: (beanClass: Class[org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient].
Unspecified value parameter beanClass.
         val patientsDataSet = patients.toDS[Patient]()
                                                     ^
```

This is what I get when I remove the parenthesis:

```
scala> val patientsDataSet = patients.toDS[Patient]
<console>:46: error: missing arguments for method toDS in class MongoRDD;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
         val patientsDataSet = patients.toDS[Patient]
```

Is there anyway, I can use a Java Object in place of a case class here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try it without the parentheses: `patients.toDS[Patient]`

Comment: @Yawar I tried it without the parenthesis and I updated my question with the error I got.

Comment: Let's try giving your `.toDS[Patient]()` method a bean class like it wants: `patients.toDS[Patient](classOf[Patient])`

Comment: @Yawar That worked. I got, what I think is a, different issue. I got a StackOverflowError. I'll ask a different question for that, but if you'd like to formally answer my question, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might work to create a case class that extends your java object.

Java:

```
public class Patient {

  private final String name;
  private final String status;

  public Patient(String name, String status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.status = status;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

}
```

Scala:

```
    case class Patient0(name: String, status: String) extends Patient(name, status)
val patientsDataSet = patients.toDS[Patient]()
val patients = sc.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://mongodb/fhir.patients")))
```

Comment: This may be difficult to implement as these domain objects have a lot of fields. For example: http://hapifhir.io/apidocs-dstu3/org/hl7/fhir/dstu3/model/Patient.html